# How do I repurpose a window's close button without affecting ALT+F4 or closing it in the taskbar?

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, window, message-queue

I am making a program with native C++ and the WinAPI.

This program has a main application window that I want to be somewhat persistent. It seems kind of natural to close a window via the red X button, and I often accidentally press it when I don't actually want to exit the program (this happens to me with Teamspeak). So, I'm trying to repurpose the red X button into a minimize button to avoid accidental exiting.

However, my application should have some way to exit the program with standard system controls. I want to allow ALT+F4 and right clicking on the taskbar icon to close. I tried intercepting WM_CLOSE and SYSCOMMAND (SC_CLOSE) but this seems to disable all standard system methods of exiting the program (short of killing it in Process Explorer - not really a standard method).

Is there a way to **only intercept the window's red X button**? I noticed that Windows Live Messenger does this but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` message and use `WM_NCHITTEST` to check it the click is about to be delivered to `HTCLOSE` control (this is what your red [X] resolves to). Or alternatively, handle `WM_NCHITTEST` itself and prevent from discovering `HTCLOSE` part of your window GUI by replacing return value with something else.

Comment: Thanks very much! It works fine, but would you by any chance know how to do this on mouse-up? This is how Windows Live Messenger does it. `WM_NCLBUTTONUP` doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Why won't you check the messages coming through with `Spy++` to see which exactly might be helpful? It is possible that `WM_NCLBUTTONUP` is delivered in the inner message loop and does not reach your hook, but maybe there is something else to help. And keep in mind the other option of handling `WM_NCHITTEST` to convert close button into "regular" button.

Comment: I am using Spy++, and `WM_NCLBUTTONUP` never seems to appear. I've tried intercepting `WM_NCHITTEST` but that message is never sent when the mouse moves over or clicks the minimize/maximize/close button. I suspect that most mouse behaviours invoke the system to internally use `WM_NCHITTEST` but I don't know how to intercept this.