# How to make C++ to execute a function when I close the console

Tags: c++, windows

I want a C++ program to execute a function when I close manually the console.
I made a C++ program that test a password and if it isn't correct make the windows to log off.
But if I close the console from the "X" button nothing happens and I want to make windows to log off too if the console is closed from "X" button?
I tried _onexit_t oe() function but it doesn't help me.
So there is a method to do that or to hide the bar which contains the "Minimize", "Maximize" and "Close" buttons?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788662/how-do-i-repurpose-a-windows-close-button-without-affecting-altf4-or-closing-i, specifically WM_CLOSE

Comment: You probably want to handle WM_CLOSE event in the window procedure.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101742/difference-between-wm-close-and-sc-close, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155782/what-is-the-difference-between-wm-quit-wm-close-and-wm-destroy-in-a-windows-pr

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean the normal textual console window, you can register your own event handler via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` and watch for the events `CTRL_C_EVENT`, `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`, `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`, `CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT`, `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT`, etc.